# IBM uDeploy unable to retrieve npm versions from artifactory

Tags: npm, artifactory, udeploy

I have a normal npm angular package published to Artifactory's npm repository
at

```
https:<artifactory host>:<port>/npm-prereleases-local/@my-scope/modulename/-/@my-scope/modulename-1.1.0.tgz
```

I am able to retrieve a list of the versioned files using a Artifactory REST service call at endpoint

```
https:<artifactory host>:<port>/api/storage/npm-prereleases-local/@my-scope/modulename/-/@my-scope
```

Returns a json with all relevant files under that path
i.e.

```
modulename-1.1.0.tgz
modulename-1.1.1.tgz
modulename-1.1.2.tgz
modulename-1.1.3.tgz
.......
```

I have configured uDeploy's component to point to the same npm-prereleases-local on artifactory.
When I run "Import Versions" on uDeploy component I see the following message indicating that it has imported versions successfully but I don't see the versions on uDeploy to be used for actual deployment.

```
......
[Action] Getting list of versions for: https:<artifactory host>:<port>/api/storage/npm-prereleases-local/@my-scope/modulename/-/@my-scope

[Ok] Finished
..........
```

Looking around, it seems like I am not the only one going through this issue, but I don't see any of those answered either, so asking again.